# Euler-Lagrange formalism with SymPy

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, python

I am trying to use [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to apply the **Euler-Lagrange formalism** to the following Lagrangian function:

$$\mathcal{L}(x, \dot{x}) = \mathcal{K}(x, \dot{x}) - \mathcal{P}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathfrak{m} \dot{x} - \mathfrak{m} g x.$$

The result should be

$$
f = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}} 
  - \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x}
  = \mathfrak{m} \ddot{x} + \mathfrak{m} g.$$

However, I get $f = \mathfrak{m} g$ with SymPy...

Below is the source of my *jupyter notebook*.

```
In [1]: from sympy import *
        from sympy.physics.mechanics import *

In [2]: m,g = symbols('m g', real=True)
        x   = dynamicsymbols('x')
        xd  = dynamicsymbols('x', 1)
        xdd = dynamicsymbols('x', 2)

In [3]: kin_energy = 1/2 * m * xd ** 2
        pot_energy = m * g * x

In [4]: L = kin_energy - pot_energy
        f = diff(L, xdd) - diff(L, x)

In [5]: pprint(f)
Out[5]: g⋅m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code

> 1/2

Depending on the version of python you're using, this could be interpreted as either '0' or '1/2'. So To avoid problems just use

```
kin_energy = 0.5 * m * xd ** 2
pot_energy = m * g * x
```

> ${\rm d}/{\rm d}t(\partial L/ \partial \dot{x})$

Note that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} \not= \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \ddot{x}}
$$

If you implement these two things, you should get

```
m = symbols('m', real = True)
g = symbols('g', real = True)
x   = dynamicsymbols('x')
xd  = dynamicsymbols('x', 1)

kin_energy = 0.5 * m * xd ** 2
pot_energy = m * g * x

L = kin_energy - pot_energy
f = diff(diff(L, xd), 't') - diff(L, x)
pprint(f)

>>>           2      
             d       
g⋅m + 1.0⋅m⋅───(x(t))
              2      
            dt
```

Comment: I am using Python 3, so the `1 / 2` should not pose a problem. I guess what I did wrong was  really the `diff(diff(L, xd), 't')`. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho happy to help